# Can't add vb class to c# project in vs 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

When I add my vb classes to my C# project in vs 2008 they are readily available to be used in my c# classes. But for some reason 2010 can't see them. I could be missing something simple but i couldn't make it work in the past hour. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you cant see them do you mean you can't access it via the namespaces or through project references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you had them included with action compile and not just action content?

CSharp and VB use two differnt MSBuild targets file and I've never heard of mixing them in the same project file.  Different project types in the same solution - sure, but not what I think you are saying.

Of course it's a strange world so maybe someone will come by and suprise me with something I never thought possible outside of ILMerge after the build.

Comment: I meant same solution. I think the problem is that they are not being converted successfully. It skips them in conversion. I am thinking about recreating them in 2010 unless you have a better suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know your dependencies.  Is it possible to put them in solutions by them selves to get the projects updated and then put them back together in the same solution?

Comment: Yup, I imported them one by one into a new project. And there was no updating required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can't mix 2 code languages. like you can add vb and vb, c# and c# but not vb and c# together.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to mix, use a code converter like c# - vb or something. Here is one to try instead of re coding it all again: [Vb.net --> C# converter](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/).

It may not be 100% working but at least you'll convert some code.